# What does the word "enchaliced" mean in John Ashbery's "A Wave"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I'm reading John Ashbery's "A Wave" and the word appears in this context:

> [ . . . ] and incorrect conclusions based on false premises that now / Slow you down but by that time, ***enchaliced***, will sound attentive, / Tonic even, an antidote to badly reasoned desiring [ . . . ]

I can't seem to locate a definition.

Comment: Look up “chaliced.”

Comment: @Xanne I did look it up (it's not a word I've come across) and I'm not sure that it helps a lot with "enchaliced". From the couple of lines of context I thought that Ashbery intended it to mean that the "incorrect conclusions based on false premises" have become so accepted over time that they have become "consecrated" like communion wine. Ashbery does seem to have coined the word though so I'm not sure.

Comment: @BoldBen Well, this is poetry.  Ashbery is talking about memories, the conclusions reached from a variety of events, conclusions that may be wrong, and are "enchaliced"--in a chalice, chaliced meaning in a cup-like flower.  But to me poetry, lyrics, etc. are not on topic, and this is a long and complex poem, so who knows?   Chalice is not an odd word.

Comment: @Xanne Very true. I wanted more context but couldn't find the poem online except as a video, probably because it's still in copyright. However Ashbery's Brittanica entry describes him as "American poet noted for the elegance, originality, and obscurity of his poetry." I think "enchaliced" is probably an example of the obscurity.

Comment: @BoldBen One thing I did was look in Google Books. The word does appear in other texts. In "The Tale of the Tear," William Carey Richards writes, "There lie, enchaliced, at his own sweet will / Light-pinioned vapours which his wand sets free." Here it makes perfect sense: enchaliced as in "held in a chalice." There are many other examples, all from the late 1800s, quite possibly the source for Ashbery's rather esoteric usage.

Comment: @Xanne "Chalice" is not an odd word at all. Still, revisiting Ashbery's usage above, it appears to be too broad to mean one possible thing. Upon rereading, it seems he could be tending towards anything from the figurative (where "chaliced" can mean "constrained," "held in a space," and so forth), to the literal (where it can wryly indicate something to the tune of "in vino veritas"). I see now that his usage will yield no single definition.